# Adding custom attributes in Zend Framework 2 using the Zend Form

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-form

What I want to achieve is to add custom attributes to the form, which are:

```
'validType' => 'remote[\'/catalogos/acl/compruebarecurso\',\'nombre\']', 
'invalidmessage' => 'Al parecer el nombre ya existe'.
```

The problem lies in the view, since it does not generate the correct HTML

```
class RecursosForm extends Form 
    { 
        // TODO - Insert your code here 

        /** 
         */ 
        public function __construct($name = null){ 
            parent::__construct($name); 

            $this->add(array( 
                    'name' => 'nombre', 
                    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Text', 
                    'attributes' => array( 
                            'class' => 'easyui-validatebox', 
                            'validType' => 'remote[\'/catalogos/acl/compruebarecurso\',\'nombre\']', 
                            'invalidmessage' => 'Al parecer el nombre ya existe' 
                    ), 
                    'options' => array( 
                            'label' => 'Recurso:', 
                            'label_attributes' => array('class'  => 'fitem'), 

                    ) 
            )); 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the HTML that is generated with your current code and the HTML that you'd like to be generated instead.

Answer (score 1):

The view helper isn't producing incorrect HTML but is actually preventing it. The attributes *you* have added would result in invalid HTML so ZF2 removes them.

You can override this by [extending the abstract form view helper and defining your own `$validAttributes`](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-form/blob/master/src/View/Helper/AbstractHelper.php#L151), although it still would result in incorrect HTML.

You should consider using the [HTML 5 custom data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) (attributes with the prefix `data-*`) as these are valid and will not be filtered out by the standard form view helpers.

```
'attributes' => [ 
    'class'                => 'easyui-validatebox', 
    'data-valid-type'      => 'remote[\'/catalogos/acl/compruebarecurso\',\'nombre\']', 
    'data-invalid-message' => 'Al parecer el nombre ya existe' 
],
```